# dynamically set scrollviewer position to end when FlowDocumentScrollViewer used in it -WPF(C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

We dynamically bind the row with `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` but problem is that scroll is not set at last row, its immediate come at top when all row fully loaded. We need to set it last when all row loaded.

That code is used for adding row :

```
this.conversation.Blocks.Add(mainbox);
```

That code used for set scroll at end but this is not working.

```
Sviewer.ScrollToEnd();
```

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="Chat_Border" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="455"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="0,0,1,0" >
                                    <ScrollViewer  Name="Sviewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Visibility="Visible"  BorderBrush="Blue"
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
                                               PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewerPreviewMouseWheel"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="5">
                                        <Border MinWidth="650" MaxWidth="750"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="50,0,0,0">

                               <FlowDocumentScrollViewer                                                                    
                                x:Name="Conversation" 
                                IsTabStop="False"                                 
                                Document="{Binding Path=Conversation, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                FontSize="12"  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"                                    
                                Focusable="True"
                               SelectionOpacity="0.5"                                            
                                IsToolBarVisible="True"               
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                                <FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocumentScrollViewer}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocumentScrollViewer}">
                                                                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                                                        <WrapPanel x:Name="ChatStateNotification"
                                                            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                                            Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" 
                                                               Foreground="{StaticResource AccentColorOrangeBrush}"
                                                               FontWeight="SemiBold">
                                                                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                                                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0}">
                                                                                        <Binding Path="TypingText" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                                                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                                                </TextBlock.Text>
                                                                            </TextBlock>
                                                                        </WrapPanel>

                                                                        <WrapPanel x:Name="GroupStateNotification"
                                                            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                                            Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" 
                                                               Foreground="{StaticResource AccentColorOrangeBrush}"
                                                               FontWeight="SemiBold">
                                                                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                                                                    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} {1}">
                                                                                        <Binding Path="Contact.DisplayName" />
                                                                                        <Binding Path="TypingText" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                                                                                        <!--<Binding Path="Contact.TypingText" />-->
                                                                                        <Binding Path="ChatStateNotification" />
                                                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                                                </TextBlock.Text>
                                                                            </TextBlock>
                                                                        </WrapPanel>
                                                                        <ScrollViewer 
                                                    x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                    BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                                    CanContentScroll="True" 
                                                    Focusable="False" 
                                                    Width="Auto" Background="Transparent" 

                                                    Height="Auto">
                                                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                                                        <AdornerDecorator x:Name="PART_ToolBarHost">
                                                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                                                        </AdornerDecorator>
                                                                    </DockPanel>
                                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ChatStateNotification}" Value="composing">

                                                                            <Setter TargetName="ChatStateNotification" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ChatStateNotification}" Value="active">
                                                                            <Setter TargetName="GroupStateNotification" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ChatStateNotification}" Value="gone">
                                                                            <Setter TargetName="GroupStateNotification" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ChatStateNotification}" Value="paused">
                                                                            <Setter TargetName="ChatStateNotification" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ChatStateNotification}" Value="inactive">
                                                                            <Setter TargetName="ChatStateNotification" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ChatStateNotification}" Value="None">
                                                                            <Setter TargetName="ChatStateNotification" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Contact.Presence.PresenceStatus}" Value="Offline">
                                                                            <Setter TargetName="ChatStateNotification" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Style>
                                            </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </ScrollViewer>
```

Please suggest what I should do

Answer (score 0):

I used this Code in constructor. It worked

```
   public Window()
            {
                      InitializeComponent();
                  DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                    //timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
                    timer.Tick += ((sender, e) =>
                    {
                        Conversation.Height += 10;

                            Sviewer.ScrollToBottom();

                    });
                    timer.Start();
    }
```